# Understanding a C++ program [ Bjarne Stroustrup's book ]

Tags: c++, string, windows, while-loop, initialization

i need your precious help for a small question!
I'm reading the Bjarne Stroustrup's book and i found this exemple:

```
int main()
{
   string previous = " ";
   string current;

   while (cin >> current) {                                    
      if(previous == current)
        cout << "repeated word: " << current << '\n';
      previous = current;
   }                                                            
   return 0;
}
```

My question is: *What does **string previous = " ";** do?*

It initializes *previous* to the character space *(like when you press space)*. But I thought in C++ it doesn't read it, something about the compiler skipping over whitespace. Why initialize it to that then?

I have tried to write like that: **string previous;** and the program still work properly... so? What is the differnece? Please enlighten me x)

Comment: with `cin >> current`, `current` *won't* ever be whitespace. Don't see any reason why just the empty string was not used, though.

Comment: Precisely *because* the input operation never produces a whitespace, a whitespace makes for a good initial value, since it's never the same as the first word. But the same reasoning applies to the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, a whitespace is something you will never get when reading input using `std::cin`. Therefore, a `previous` string is initialized with a value that could never (i.e. when reading the first word) possibly match word read into `current` string.

In this case `previous` could alsobe initalized to an empty string, because `istream::operator>>` skips all the whitespace and you would never get an empty like by reading from `std::cin` that way. However, there are other ways of using `std::cin` (e.g. together with `getline()`), which may lead to reading an empty string.

[The book explains this example in every detail](https://books.google.pl/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: But if i write an empty line for exemple if i press just enter, the program doesn't show me the output "repated word". So? ( and my code is with string previus; not string previus = " "; )

Comment: @RavenJe yes, it looks like reading an empty string is impossible when using `istream::operator>>` (however, it could still be possible when using `cin` for example with getline). I will edit my question.

Comment: So why bjarne writed like that? Is an exemple for the students? Just for let me know that a whitespace is something i will never get when reading input using std::cin?

Answer (score 4):

You seam to be confused on what it means in C++ to ignore whitespace.  In C++

```
std::string the_string = something;
```

is treated the same as

```
std::string      the_string=something          ;
```

No when you have a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) the whitespace in the literal is not ignored as it is part of the charcters of the string.  So

```
std::string foo = " ";
```

Creates a string with one space where as

```
std::string foo = "    ";
```

Creates a string with 4 spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string previous = " ";
```

assigns a space to the string variable 'previous'.

It may still 'work', but if you were to simply press enter on the first try, the 'repeated word' message should appear.

Comment: Not quite. `cin` will not return on only enter. Not no string. Not space. `cin` will wait until non-whitespace is entered, so entering `<space><enter>` won't do jack, either.

Answer (score 1):

He could just write :)

```
string previous;
```

The idea is that the `operator >>` can not enter an empty string if by default there is set to skip white spaces.

So any comparison `current` with an empty string or a string that contains white spaces will yield `false`.